# AJAX response, cant alert JSON String properly

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

Im finding a strange problem.

Using php i am running a select query on mysql database, i am trying to return this to my ajax call so i can for loop through it, but i always get undefined as an alert, i can alert the whole json string however, but cant target values.

Ajax code:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'database_data.php',
            data: {
                action: 'ct',
                input: input
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                alert(obj[0].pid);
                alert(data[0].pid);
            },error: function(request, status, error){
                alert("Error: Could not delete");
            }
        });
```

PHP Code:

```
$base= mysqli_connect($dbhost,  $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbbase);
if ($_POST['action']== "ct"){
  $input = $_POST['input'];
  $return_arr = array();
  $sql = "SELECT pid FROM programmes WHERE complete_title LIKE '%$input%' LIMIT 30";

if ($result = mysqli_query( $base, $sql )){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $row_array['pid'] = $row['pid'];
        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }
}

mysqli_close($base);

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

}

Alerting data gives a response as so:

```
[{"pid":"p00547jm"},{"pid":"p0054880"},{"pid":"p005492h"},...
```

If i chose to alert data[0], data[1] it prints each individual character

Comment: `$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});`  Add dataType, or use the shorthand: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: You are alerting `data[0]` which is not parsed.

Comment: `obj` is an array, so you need to use the proper index there: `obj[0].pid`

Comment: @CBroe , initially it did not work like that either, the reason why i ddnt have it indexed when submitting question cos i was trialling every possibility lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dataType` to tell jquery what you are expecting back from the server. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

In your case

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'database_data.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                action: 'ct',
                input: input
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var obj = data; // I should already be json!
                alert(obj.pid);
                alert(data.pid);
            },error: function(request, status, error){
                alert("Error: Could not delete");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are probably getting string as a response. So your `data` is a `string`.

You can use `JSON.parse()` to parse it into JSON object and the access the data like this,

```js
data = '[{"pid":"p00547jm"},{"pid":"p0054880"},{"pid":"p005492h"}]';

console.log(JSON.parse(data)[0].pid);
```

Comment: @bigbounty he still needs to access the proper array elements first.